# node+now.js+connect gives me an error

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect, nowjs-sockets

I installed the node_module connect to use the static method. This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var nowjs = require("now");
var app = connect();

app.use(connect.static('/var/www/www.domain.com/htdocs'));

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8001);


var everyone = nowjs.initialize(http);
```

But I get an error:

```
[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'listeners'] TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'listeners'
    at Object.wrapServer (/home/chris/nowjs/node_modules/now/lib/fileServer.js:23:29)
    at [object Object].initialize (/home/chris/nowjs/node_modules/now/lib/now.js:181:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris/nowjs/multiroomchat_server.js:15:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Does this help? `var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8001);
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);`

Comment: yes it did! thanks! Please post it as an answer so i can approve it :)

Comment: one following question: Its working fine with .html files, but if I open up localhost:3000/test.php it gives me test.php to download..

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you open test.php? `connect.static` certainly isn't going to run the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Yeah obviously...but is it somehow possible so that it works with .php files too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `http` variable is a reference to the http module, not the created http service. You need to take the variable passed back from the `createServer()` and pass that to Now.js. Thankfully `listen()` chains it and you don't have to break up the line.

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8001);
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);
```